# I want to send a parameter in a dictionary format while selecting or deselecting should add or remove elements from the dictionary

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, dictionary

HI I'm trying to send a dictionary format array to an API call. But I don't have any idea to send that in swift. my fellow android developer send me the following code he sent.

```
for (int i = 0; i < CheckedName.size(); i++) {
JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
j.put("product", CheckedName.get(i));
j.put("quantity", CheckedQty.get(i));
jsonCategoryArray.put(j);
```

}
finalObject.put("products", jsonCategoryArray);

I want to send as following format

```
{“products”:[{“product”:“1711”,“quantity”:“2”},{“product”:“1713”,“quantity”:“1”},{“product”:“1718”,“quantity”:“3”},{“product”:“444”,“quantity”:“1”},{“product”:“6”,“quantity”:“1”},{“product”:“4914”,“quantity”:“1”},{“product”:“921”,“quantity”:“1”},{“product”:“11835”,“quantity”:“1”},{“product”:“11946”,“quantity”:“1”},{“product”:“12046”,“quantity”:“1”},{“product”:“12326”,“quantity”:“1”},{“product”:“12571”,“quantity”:“1”},{“product”:“273”,“quantity”:“1”},{“product”:“13410”,“quantity”:“1”},{“product”:“13435”,“quantity”:“1”},{“product”:“13665”,“quantity”:“1”},{“product”:“13795”,“quantity”:“1”},{“product”:“3553”,“quantity”:“1”}]}
```

I tried following method on my table delegates but I'm not sure that will work.. any one help me out on this.

didSelect method

```
self.productDic["product"] = self.productIDString
 self.productDic["quantity"] = self.productQtyString
 self.productArray.append(self.productDic)
```

don't know how to remove from didDeselect method...
this is giving me following format

```
Product Dictionary : [["product": "3004", "quantity": "1"], ["product": "1716", "quantity": "1"]]
```

After that I have to pass product array as this

```
param = ["products":self.productArray] as [String : AnyObject]
    AF.request("\(base_url)basket/mass/add/", method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: URLEncoding(), headers: headers).validate(statusCode: 200..<299).responseJSON { response in
       print("sent param to selected shopping products \(param)")
```

Please help me an easy method to acheive this than my method or help me to remove values to the same array from didDeselect method . I'm stuck on this.

Comment: "don't know how to remove from didDeselect method.", "remove values to the same array " what does this mean? What is it you want to remove, it is hard to understand what your problem is?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I want to add and remove elements from didSelect and didDeselect method. I will edit the question clearly.

Answer (score 0):

To create JSON as you required for API request is like.

```
{"products":[{"product":"1711","quantity":"2"},{"product":"1713","quantity":"1"}}
```

In didSelect method just add selected items in array or you can add an isSelected flag in the model to check what the user selected.

For example model:

```
struct Product {
    var product: Int
    var quantity: Int

  //Helper property
    var isSelected: Bool = false
}
```

Now, inside didSelect method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
  products[indexPath.row].isSelected = !products[indexPath.row].isSelected
}
```

Finally, when you want to hit API just filter all the selected items from the products list like this.

```
    let selectedProducts = products.filter({$0.isSelected})
```

Now, creating JSON:

```
extension Dictionary {
    var jsonStringRepresentation: String? {
        guard let theJSONData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self,
                                                        options: [])      else {
                                                            return nil
    }
    
      return String(data: theJSONData, encoding: .ascii)
    }
 }

private func createJSON(from list: [Product]) -> String {
     var productDic = [[String: String]]()
     for item in list {
        let param = ["product": "\(item.product)", "quantity": "\(item.quantity)"]
        productDic.append(param)
     }

     let finalDictionary = ["products": productDic]
     return finalDictionary.jsonStringRepresentation ?? ""
    }

   print(createJSON(from: products))
```